# A proper way to synchronize commands for buffer operation in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

Please imagine a situation like this: We need to transition layouts of two image buffers and then copy the data from one to another. Also, we don't want to have any delays in code by involving **Idle** or **Fence** operations - because we want these operations be called often and in flight

As far as I can understand Vulkan doesn't guarantee any order or subsequence of commands submitted via a command buffers, only if it wasn't explicitly stated the opposite.

Would the only possible way to do this be the two command buffer submissions with usage of one semaphore? Like in the pseudocode below:

```
Image stagingImage;
Image image;

CommandBuffer cb1;
cb1.TransitionLayout(stagingImage, vk::ImageLayout::eTransferSrcOptimal);
cb1.TransitionLayout(image, vk::ImageLayout::eTransferDstOptimal);

CommandBuffer cb2;
cb2.copyImage(stagingImage.image, stagingImage.imageLayout, image->image, image->imageLayout, __region__);

Queue transferQueue;
vk::Semafore semaphore;

vk::SubmitInfo submitInfo1({}, {}, cb1, signalSemaphores: { semaphore });
transferQueue.submit(submitInfo1);

//I just wait for two (possibly parallel) transition layouts to complete before asking for a copy
vk::SubmitInfo submitInfo2(waitSemaphores: { semaphore }, waitStages: { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT }, cb2, {});
transferQueue.submit(submitInfo2);
```

*One of these image buffers is obviously a staging and it should be deleted synchronously, but it is possible to create a fence for the copy buffer operation (submitInfo2), and then check this fence once a frame and delete the staging buffer when operations with it will be done*

Also, do I understand properly that I wouldn't have to establish any memory barriers when all commands work in one pseudo pipeline stage (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT), if it wasn't required to ?

Comment: "*One of these image buffers is obviously a staging and it should be deleted synchronously*" Why would you delete a staging buffer? Are you finished staging and will never ever do staging again? If not, there's no reason to delete it; you can simply reuse it when the time comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I can understand Vulkan doesn't guarantee any order or subsequence of commands submitted via a command buffers

Layout transitions are part of memory barriers, which are themselves part of execution dependencies of some sort. So synchronization is built in... assuming you did it correctly.

I don't know what this code means:

> ```
> cb1.TransitionLayout(stagingImage, vk::ImageLayout::eTransferSrcOptimal);
> cb1.TransitionLayout(image, vk::ImageLayout::eTransferDstOptimal);
> ```

But I see a lack of many things here. There's no specification of what the source or destination operations (stages and access forms) for the memory barriers that these function calls presumably generate. So I would assume that this synchronziation operation is a hard barrier between every pipeline stage and all forms of access. That's... not good.

Nor does it make any kind of sense to do these back-to-back instead of in the same barrier.

Basically, this is a bad API that doesn't let you actually express the intent of what you're doing. If it does do a hard barrier of everything with everything else, that will *function*, but it can also be bad for performance.

The semaphores and multiple submit commands are completely unnecessary.